# Does anybody recognize this anime with a military parade?

Tags: xamd-lost-memories

I'm afraid I don't have any information about this anime except a single screenshot and the source where I got it (AMV).

Here's the picture:

[image]

And the AMV is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaHr444rzf4). The reason I'm pasting the AMV link is because it may contain more scenes from the above anime (as it did have different scenes from some animes I knew).

Thanks for any help/guesses.

Comment: What timeslot is your picture from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is from the third ED of *Xam'd: Lost Memories*.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mU1MbPWyf8

The figure in the center is Toujirou Kakisu.